# Using array to change ToggleButton visibility on/off (AS3/Flex)

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, apache-flex

So I'm trying to be able to change the visibility of an array of togglebuttons that I have right now. Using the flex interface tool, I made 10 toggle buttons and named their caller IDs b1,b2,b3...etc. I then placed those IDs into the array I mentioned. I also have a numeric stepper which I changed the called ID to numericstepper.

```
 var buttonArray: Array= new Array (b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10)//global ;

 protected function numericstepper_changeHandler(event:Event):void {
 var x:int=0
 var y:int
 x=numericstepper.value //the value of the numericstepper
 for (y=0; y<x; y++) {
 buttonArray[y].visible= false // trying to change the visibility of each         button in the array
 }
```

But this doesn't work and gives me an error. Actually, even when I just trace buttonArray[1] it gives me null....not sure what to do here.

Newbie coder here so please advise!

Comment: what kind of error do you have? also trace array and array.length in the numericstepper_changeHandler. are you sure it had been initialized before the handler was executed?

Answer (score 0):

ok I probably know what the problem is: you are creating the array variable in a component, but at that time (on construction of the component) that buttons are uninitialized yet (i.e `== null`). Common practice is to wait for some of the component's life cycle event before working with inner components. Usually it is the `creationComplete` event.

something like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<s:Application xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark"
        creationComplete="onCreationComplete()">
    <fx:Script><![CDATA[
        private var buttonArray:Array;

        private function onCreationComplete():void {
            buttonArray = [b1, b2, b3, b4, b5, b6, b7, b8, b9, b10];
        }

        protected function numericstepper_changeHandler(event:Event):void {
            const x:int = numericstepper.value;
            for (var i:int = 0; i < x; i++) {
                buttonArray[i].visible = false;
            }
        }
        ]]></fx:Script>
        <!-- inner components here -->
</s:Application>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is indeed a newbie error. You need to understand the difference between variables and objects. b1 is a variable, a ToggleButton is an object, a variable holds a reference to an object but is not the object itself, it is just a reference. So in your case you correctly add your variable to an array but at this point those variable do not reference any objects so in that case their default value (what they really reference) is "null". null is a special type of object that has no methods and no properties and can be used in place of any complex object.

When you add those variables b1, b2, etc to an array you truly add what they reference, you do not add the variable themselves to the array so whatever the variable reference get in the array so in your case it's 'null'.

To make sure you add the ToggleButton objects you can simply delay everything and check for value for example:

```
var buttonArray: Array;

protected function numericstepper_changeHandler(event:Event):void 
{
    if(!buttonArray && b1)//b1 is not null so time to fill the array
    {
        buttonArray = [b1,b2,b3,b4,b5,b6,b7,b8,b9,b10];
    }
    else if(!b1)
    {
         return;//still no b1 so exit.
    }
    const x:int = numericstepper.value;
    for (var i:int = 0; i < x; i++) 
     {
        buttonArray[i].visible = false;
    }
}
```